# Accessing memory outside of array, binary heap tree

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, heap, binary-tree

For a class I was giving an assignment to take input from the command line and create a heap tree with the input. Numbers are read in from the command line.

For example:

Sample Input:

> *./Heapify 2 9 7 6 5 8*

Sample Output:

> *9 6 8 2 5 7*

I get that much to work, and it seems like every input with 6 numbers or less works fine. When an input is 7 or more numbers like this:

Sample Input:

> ./Heapify 3 10 8 7 5 9 6

My output:

> 32767 10 9 6 8 7 5

something goes wrong. Obviously I either use to much memory in my program and get a 'crap' number or I am accessing memory outside of my array which results in another 'crap' number. I have been thinking about what could be wrong but I am just not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

If you have questions or need clarity on it don't hesitate to ask.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void heap(int *array, int n);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int array[argc+1];
    int length = argc+1;

    for(int i = 1; i < length-1; i++){
        array[i]=atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    array[0]= -1;
    cout << "unheapified array: ";
    for(int k = 1; k < length-1; k++){
        cout << array[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    heap(array, length);

    cout << "heapified array: ";
    for(int k = 1; k < length-1; k++){
        cout << array[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
return 0;
}

void heap(int *array, int n){
    int i, v, j,k;
    bool heap;

    for(int i=(n/2); i>0; --i){
        k = i;
        v = array[k];
        heap = false;

        while(heap == false && (2*k) <= n-1){
            j = 2*k;
            if(j<n){
                if(array[j] < array[j+1])
                    j += 1;
            }
            if (v >= array[j])
                heap = true;
            else{
                array[k] = array[j];
                k = j;
            }
        }       
        array[k] = v;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?  Or printing out intermediate values?

Comment: You're wasting 1 index in your array; `array[0]` is never used. :(

Comment: I am using SSH to code this, do you know of a tutorial on how to use the debugger?

Comment: Arrays of non-constant size are non standard in C++ (it's standard in C99, however). I suggest you use a vector instead.

Comment: @AusCBloke i can't use the array[0] because when you try to the for loop within the function 2*0 is 0 so you will not do anything and nothing will be swapped.

Comment: @NaySayer: You can make some very small changes to make a heapify work with 0-based arrays, as opposed to 1-based arrays a lot of resources use. ie. left child = `(parent * 2) + 1`, right = `(parent * 2) + 2`, parent = `(child - 1) / 2`.

Comment: @NaySayer: Welcome to Satckoverflow. If the answer that was given to you fits your needs, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `heap` function like this:

```
    while(heap == false && (2*k) <= n-1){
        j = 2*k;
        if(j<n){
            assert((j+1)<n); // ADDED THIS
            if(array[j] < array[j+1])
                j += 1;
        }
```

You'll see the `assert` gets tripped. So `array[j+1]` is off the end.

Comment: [#include <cassert>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/) will do it.